# Return a generic nullable Element

Tags: c#, .net, generics, nullable

I'm trying to make a method that returns the highest value of an `Array` with generic elements that can be `Nullable`.

```
 public T Greatest<T>(T?[] array) where T : struct, IComparable<T> 
 {
     T? Greater = null;
     foreach (var elem in array)
     {
         if(elem.HasValue)
         {
             if(Greater.HasValue)
             {
                 if(Greater.Value.CompareTo(elem.Value) < 0)
                 {
                     Greater = elem;
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 Greater = elem;
             }
        }
    }

    //Problem here: What is the best way to return the greatest value?
    // ****
    return Greater.Value; // Possible InvalidOperationException 
    // ****
}
```

What is the proper way to return the value?

Comment: Since you`re just *enumerating* the input, you might consider passing in an IEnumerable<T> rather than the array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Nullable.GetValueOrDefault](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72cec0e0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

You can simplify your method:

```
public T Greatest<T>(T?[] array) where T : struct, IComparable<T> 
{
    return array.Max().GetValueOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply change the method to return `T?` and then return `Greater`. If the greatest value isn't a value at all, why pretend that it is? On the other hand, if you *really* need to return some kind of non-nullable value, then you *can* do

```
if (Greater.HasValue)
    return Greater.Value;
else 
    return /* define your default here */
```

However, defining a default that is appropriate for all types `T` would be difficult, so you can also rely on the automatic default of the type.

```
return Greater.GetValueOrDefault(); // returns either Value or default(T)
```

Which is the functional equivalent of

```
if (Greater.HasValue)
    return Greater.Value;
else 
    return default(T);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get your method to compile, you could pull the default.

```
return (Greater.HasValue) ?
            Greater.Value :
            default(T);
```

That said, if you're using a modern version of C#, you should not be writing this method in the first place and should instead be using [Enumerable.Max()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.max.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

OP said

> What is the properly [sic] way to return the Value?

The proper way is to not reinvent the wheel:

```
public T Greatest<T>( IEnumerable<T?> list ) where T : struct, IComparable<T> 
{
    return list.Where(  x => x.HasValue )
               .Select( x => x.Value    )
               .Max()
               ;
}
```